# Sleeping after every Selenium function call

Tags: python, selenium, python-3.x

I want to wait some number of seconds after a selenium call is executed, so that the user who executes the automated test can see what's happening on the screen.

My question is: Is there a way to wait some number of seconds (using implicit or explicit waits or whatever) after every function call that's better than writing `time.sleep` a bunch of times in the code? A selenium function call looks like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_name("Account").click()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to put every selenium call into its own function, and use a decorator:

```
def wait(secs):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
            time.sleep(secs)
            return ret
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Usage:

```
@wait(5) # waits 5 seconds after running the method
def do_instruction1(...):
    return "hi"

@wait(3) # waits 3 seconds after running the method
def do_instruction2(...):
    return "there"

a = do_instruction1()
print a
b = do_instruction2()
print b
```

Output:

```
<5 second delay>
"hi"
<3 second delay>
"there"
```

If you don't want to put every operation in its own function, you can do this using a coroutine:

```
import time
from functools import wraps

class Return(Exception):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

def sleeper(func):
    """ Coroutine decorator that sleeps after every yield. 

    Any yield inside a function decorated with sleeper will
    result in a 3 second sleep after the operation being
    yielded has run.

    """
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        def execute(gen):
            try:
                x = next(gen)
                time.sleep(3)
                while True:
                    x = gen.send(x)
                    time.sleep(3)
            except (Return, StopIteration) as e:
                return getattr(e, "value", None)
        gen = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return execute(gen)
    return wrapper

def f():
    print "should sleep"
    return "abc"

def g(val):
    print "should also sleep"
    return "%s-def" % (val,)

def h():
    print "this won't sleep"
    return "ghi"

@sleeper
def test():
    z = yield f()
    print "hey there, got %s" % (z,)
    y = yield g(z)
    print "ok: %s" % (y,)
    l = h()
    print "see %s" % (l,)
    z = yield f()
    print "done %s" % z
    raise Return("all done") # You can use return "all done" if you have Python 3.x


if __name__ == "__main__":
    final = test()
    print "final is %s" % final
```

Output:

```
should sleep
<3 second sleep>
hey there, got abc
should also sleep
<3 second sleep>
ok: abc-def
this won't sleep
see ghi
should sleep
<3 second sleep>
done abc
final is all done
```

Using this approach, any method you decorate with the `sleeper` coroutine will sleep after calling any method you `yield` from. So in your case, instead of calling

```
driver.find_element_by_name("Account").click()
```

You would call

```
yield driver.find_element_by_name("Account").click()
```

The only limitation is all of the calls you want to sleep after must be inside of a function decorated with `sleeper`, and that if you're using Python 2 and you want to `return` something from the decorated function, you need to use `raise Return(value)` instead of `return value`. On Python 3.x, `return value` will work fine.

Comment: An instruction would be like: "driver.find_element_by_name("Account").click()".

Comment: That seems to work. I will check the results as soon as possible and comment here. Early upvote for all the clear samples and effort

Comment: @almanegra Thanks. One note: I forgot to include the definition for the `Return` class in the original edit. I've added it now.

Comment: I've tested now and it works perfectly. Sorry for being late :)